# Searching for a pattern that includes square brackets with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to match a pattern with awk that contains square brackets. The pattern I am trying to match is:

```
[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]
```

where `PROCESS_ID` and `ID` are existing shell variables. I have tried defining a pattern variable in my awk statement:

```
awk -v pattern="[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]" '$0 ~ pattern && /GCLInbox run FINE/' $innerfile
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=logset1/teach-node-06.40490.log FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Invalid range end: /[senderProcess:teach-node-06:40190:val:67]/
```

I took this as the awk shell interpreting the square brackets as regex special characters, so I tried escaping the brackets:

```
... pattern="\[senderProcess...$ID\]" ...
```

This gives the same error, in addition to the following two errors:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'
```

I have also tried double escaping the brackets, with the same result.

I have tried using single quotes instead of double when declaring pattern, however I get the same errors, and regardless, my shell variables need to be expanded which would not happen here.

I just want to match the given pattern **including** its square brackets, whether that be by bypassing the regex special characters or some other way. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: `pattern = "[[] ... []]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `index` function of `awk` try following code. Setting some test values to shell variables named `ID` and `PROCESS_ID` though its advised to have shell variable names in small case just going with your samples here. Then create a shell variable named `var` which is having concatenation of above mentioned 2 shell variables and then passing `var` to `awk` program.

```bash
ID="test1"
PROCESS_ID="test"
var="[senderProcess:${PROCESS_ID}:val:${ID}]"
awk -v pattern="$var" 'index($0,pattern) && /GCLInbox run FINE/' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and my program was hanging indefinitely. What I think is happening is awk is trying to find the literal pattern [senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID] and not the pattern with expanded shell variables, which might look something like [senderProcess:teach-node-06:40190:val:15] depending on their current values. Any thoughts?

Comment: @CJRook43, Are you passing shell variable to this? Is `$PROCESS_ID` a shell variable?

Comment: that's correct, yes. That's my problem, I want to take the pattern as a literal string so the square brackets aren't considered special characters by regex, but if I take it as a literal string, my shell variables won't be expanded.

Comment: @CJRook43, Ok try my edited code, where I created 2 shell variables named `ID` and `PROCESS_ID`(have set their values as **dummy** ones) and then created a all in all shell variable named `var` which is further passed to `awk` program, kindly do check it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: sorry I couldn't get back to you earlier. Setting the pattern as a string outside of the awk command (interestingly) worked and the problem's solved. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Creating the dynamic REGEX, you can include `'['` and `']'` within a list `[...]` and have each identified as the character instead of the start/end of a list.

I would try something similar to:

```bash
awk -v pattern="[[]senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID[]]" 'pattern && /GCLInbox run FINE/' $innerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow when i directly set it as `FS`, without escaping, it worked, but only because `awk` just treated it as a single character class, and thus all letters inside are valid :

```
echo '[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]' |
```

> ```
> mawk -v FS='[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]' '!_<NF'
> gawk -v FS='[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]' '!_<NF'
> nawk -v FS='[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]' '!_<NF'
> ```

```
[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]
```

to do it properly :

```
gawk 'index($-_,__)' __='[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]'

[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]
```

to escape everything you need :

> ```
>  mawk  -v __='[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]' '
>  BEGIN {   _=__
>    gsub("[[-_!-/:-@{-~]", "[&]",_) 
>    gsub("["\\^/]",      "\\\\&",_)
>
>    printf("%s original pattern :\f%s\n after escaping :\f%s%s",
>                              ORS = "\n\n",__,_,ORS) > ("/dev/stderr") 
> _*=__=_ } ($_)~__'
> ```

```
 original pattern :
                   [senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID]
 after escaping :
                 [[]senderProcess[:][$]PROCESS[_]ID[:]val[:][$]ID[]]

[senderProcess:$PROCESS_ID:val:$ID
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried double escaping the brackets, with the same result.

You were close, you might get desired result by using `\\\`, consider following simple example let `file.txt` content be

```
[]
[1]
[12]
```

then

```
awk -v pattern="\\\[.\\\]" '$0 ~ pattern' file.txt
```

gives output

```
[1]
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: `echo '[1]\n[12]\n[123]' | gawk '($-_)~__' __='[[].]'`  also gives `[1]`